# Issues with Mosaicking Sentinel-2 Images in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am getting the following error code: Line 45: NSSent.mosaic is not a function. I looked online and I can't determine why it isn't working. Any ideas?

I will add that the intent is to export a single 4 band geo tiff for the entire study area (the province of NS). Right now the export are multiple median images but I would like one final image as an output.
//1 Mask Clouds
function maskS2clouds(sentColl) {
var qa = sentColl.select('QA60');

```
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return sentColl.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
//2. Define Sentinel-2 Image Collection
var sentColl = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2023-01-01')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(06, 8, 'month')) 
                  .filterMetadata ('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)
                  .filterBounds(AOI)
                  //.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                 
print(sentColl);

//4. Compute the median in each band and each pixel and then select RGBI bands. Band names are B2_Median, B3_Median etc.
 var imgMed = sentColl.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
.select('B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median');
print(imgMed)
 //5. Output image. Add it to map.
var VisualizeP = {
bands:['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median'],
min:0.012,
max:0.145,
gamma:1.30,
};
//Map.addLayer(imgMed,VisualizeP);
Map.centerObject(AOI,10);

//Clip image
var NSSent = imgMed.clip(AOI)
// Map.addLayer(NSSent,VisualizeP,);
 
 //Mosaic Sentinel-2 imagery
var sentmosaic =NSSent.mosaic();
var VisualizeP = {
bands:['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median'],
min:0.012,
max:0.145,
gamma:1.30,
};
Map.addlayer(Sentmosaic,VisualizeP)

//Export Sentinel-2 Mosaic
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:Sentmosaic,
  description: '2019_2023NSGS',
  scale: 5,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels:16792443500
})

//Calculate NDVI using the Median mosaic Image
var ndvi = Sentmosaic.normalizedDifference(['B8_median', 'B4_median']).rename('NDVI');
print(ndvi)
//Display NDVI
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'NDVI');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndvi,
  description: '2019_2023NDVI',
  scale: 5,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
})
```